# Cannot use IARG_MEMORYREAD_SIZE on non-standard memory access of instruction at 0x7ffbdcbe4e88: xsave ptr [rsp+0x40]

Tags: c++, instrumentation, intel-pin

I'm trying to use Intel Pin for investigating memory activity of an executable. And I tried to use `IARG_MEMORYREAD_SIZE` parameter. Here is the source code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <zlib.h>
#include <set>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "pin.H"

using namespace std;

#define LINE_SIZE 50


/* Traces generation parameters*/  
#define WARMUP_WINDOW 100E6
#define RUNNING_WINDOW 200E9
#define REST_WINDOW 3E9

#define NUMBER_OF_WINDOWS 2
#define PREFIX_TRACE "memory_trace_"


enum State
{
    outROI,
    warming,
    running,
    resting,
};


State state;
int nb_windows;
uint64_t cpt_time;
uint64_t accessPhase;
char buffer[LINE_SIZE];

set<int> idThreads;

PIN_LOCK lock;
gzFile trace;

using namespace std;

VOID access(uint64_t pc , uint64_t addr, int type, int size, int id_thread)
{
    PIN_GetLock(&lock, id_thread);

    idThreads.insert(id_thread);

    if(state != outROI)
    {
        if(nb_windows < NUMBER_OF_WINDOWS)
        {

            if(state == resting && accessPhase == REST_WINDOW)
            {
                cout << "PINTOOLS:BEGIN OF INSTRUMENTATION" << endl;
                accessPhase = 0;        
                state = warming;
                std::string trace_str = string(PREFIX_TRACE) + to_string(nb_windows) + ".out";              
                trace = gzopen(trace_str.c_str(), "wb8");
            }
            else if(state == warming && accessPhase == WARMUP_WINDOW)
            {
                cout << "PINTOOLS:END OF WARMUP" << endl;
                state = running;
                accessPhase = 0;
            }
            else if(state == running && accessPhase == RUNNING_WINDOW)
            {
                state = resting;
                accessPhase = 0;

                nb_windows++;
                gzclose(trace);
                cout << "PINTOOLS:END OF INSTRUMENTATION" << endl;
            }


            if(state == running || state == warming)
            {
                sprintf(buffer, "#!0x%lx %d %d %d 0x%lx" , addr , type , size , id_thread, pc);
                gzwrite(trace, buffer, LINE_SIZE);
            }
            accessPhase++;  
        }
        else
        {
            PIN_ExitApplication(0);
        }
        cpt_time++;
    }
    PIN_ReleaseLock(&lock);
}



/* Record Instruction Fetch */
VOID RecordMemInst(VOID* pc, int size, int id_thread)
{
    uint64_t convert_pc = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(pc);   
    access(convert_pc , convert_pc , 0 , size , id_thread);
}


/* Record Data Read Fetch */
VOID RecordMemRead(VOID* pc , VOID* addr, int size, int id_thread)
{
    uint64_t convert_pc = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(pc);
    uint64_t convert_addr = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(addr);
    access(convert_pc , convert_addr , 1 , size , id_thread);
}


/* Record Data Write Fetch */
VOID RecordMemWrite(VOID * pc, VOID * addr, int size, int id_thread)
{
    uint64_t convert_pc = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(pc);
    uint64_t convert_addr = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(addr);
    access(convert_pc , convert_addr , 2 , size , id_thread);
}

VOID Routine(RTN rtn, VOID *v)
{           
    RTN_Open(rtn);

    for (INS ins = RTN_InsHead(rtn); INS_Valid(ins); ins = INS_Next(ins)){

        INS_InsertCall(ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)RecordMemInst,
            IARG_INST_PTR,
            IARG_UINT32,
            INS_Size(ins),
            IARG_THREAD_ID,
            IARG_END);

            UINT32 memOperands = INS_MemoryOperandCount(ins);   

        for (UINT32 memOp = 0; memOp < memOperands; memOp++){
            if (INS_MemoryOperandIsRead(ins, INS_InsertPredicatedCallmemOp))
            {
                (
                ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)RecordMemRead,
                IARG_INST_PTR,
                IARG_MEMORYOP_EA, memOp,
                IARG_MEMORYREAD_SIZE,
                IARG_THREAD_ID,
                IARG_END);
            }



            if (INS_MemoryOperandIsWritten(ins, memOp))
            {
                INS_InsertPredicatedCall(
                ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)RecordMemWrite,
                IARG_INST_PTR,
                IARG_MEMORYOP_EA, memOp,

/**************************wrong happend here*************************/

                IARG_MEMORYREAD_SIZE,
                IARG_THREAD_ID,
                IARG_END);
            }
        }
    }
    RTN_Close(rtn);
}


VOID Fini(INT32 code, VOID *v)
{
    cout << "PINTOOLS:NB Access " << cpt_time << endl;
    cout << "PINTOOLS:NB Threads " << idThreads.size() << endl;
//  cout << ""
//  if(state != outROI)
//  {
    gzclose(trace); 
//  }

}

/* ===================================================================== */
/* Print Help Message                                                    */
/* ===================================================================== */

INT32 Usage()
{
    return -1;
}

/* ===================================================================== */
/* Main                                                                  */
/* ===================================================================== */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{



    PIN_InitLock(&lock);

    nb_windows=0;
    cpt_time =0;
    accessPhase = 0;

    RTN_AddInstrumentFunction(Routine, 0);

    PIN_AddFiniFunction(Fini, 0);

    state = running;


    PIN_StartProgram();

    return 0;
}
```

After compilation I am trying to run it by Pin like this:

> ## /home/kolin/cache/pin-2.14-71313-gcc.4.4.7-linux/pin  -ifeellucky -injection child -follow-execv -t /home/kolin/cache-simulator-master/utils/pintools-trace-gen/obj-intel64/trace-gen.so -- ../run_base_test_gcc41-64bit.0000/gcc_base.gcc41-64bit cccp.in -o cccp.s

But I received this error:

> E: src/trace-gen.cc:161: Cannot use IARG_MEMORYREAD_SIZE on non-standard memory access of instruction at 0x7ffbdcbe4e88: xsave ptr [rsp+0x40].

I've never meet this error before, does anybody have any idea about what am I doing wrong?

(This program is from https://github.com/gvaumour/cache-simulator)

Comment: This might fall under the case where you need to use `IARG_MULTI_MEMORYACCESS_EA` (see the [documentation](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/97503/Pin/html/group__INST__ARGS.html#gga089c27ca15e9ff139dd3a3f8a6f8451dad2e2d24103d1a0286b57412f66b909d7)). You can check if you can use `IARG_MEMORYREAD_SIZE` or not with [`INS_hasKnownMemorySize`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/97503/Pin/html/group__INS__BASIC__API__IA32.html#ga286e936047a0257324b948dce216b8eb).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I wrote a more complete answer which might also help people who stumble upon the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might fall under the case where you need to use `IARG_MULTI_MEMORYACCESS_EA` (see the [documentation](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/97503/Pin/html/group__INST__ARGS.html#gga089c27ca15e9ff139dd3a3f8a6f8451dad2e2d24103d1a0286b57412f66b909d7)).

Basically, according to the [XSAVE documentation](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/xsave) the number of bytes written to the memory pointed by the instruction is not constant and depends on the following factors:

- The requested-feature bitmap (RFBM)
- The logical-AND of EDX:EAX
- The logical-OR of XCR0 with the IA32_XSS MSR

You can check if you can use `IARG_MEMORYREAD_SIZE` (constant memory sized instruction) or not with [`INS_hasKnownMemorySize`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/97503/Pin/html/group__INS__BASIC__API__IA32.html#ga286e936047a0257324b948dce216b8eb).

```cpp
            if (INS_MemoryOperandIsWritten(ins, memOp))
            {
                // known memory size (standard behavior)
                if(INS_hasKnownMemorySize(ins)) {
                    INS_InsertPredicatedCall(
                    ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)RecordMemWrite,
                    IARG_INST_PTR,
                    IARG_MEMORYOP_EA, memOp,
                    IARG_MEMORYREAD_SIZE,
                    IARG_THREAD_ID,
                    IARG_END);
                } else {
                // multi memory access
                    INS_InsertPredicatedCall(
                    ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)RecordMemWriteMulti, // use another analysis routine
                    IARG_INST_PTR,
                    IARG_MEMORYOP_EA, memOp,
                    IARG_MULTI_MEMORYACCESS_EA, // the analysis routine gets a PIN_MULTI_MEM_ACCESS_INFO*
                    IARG_THREAD_ID,
                    IARG_END);
                }
            }
```

The `PIN_MULTI_MEM_ACCESS_INFO` structure is [documented here](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/97619/Pin/html/structPIN__MULTI__MEM__ACCESS__INFO.html).